# Build pandas dataframe in for loop

Tags: for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop that iterates over a dataframe and calculates two pieces of information:

```
for id in members['id']
    x = random_number_function()
    y = random_number_function()
```

I'd like to store id, x and y in a dataframe that is built one row at a time, for each pass through the for loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to build a dataframe one row at a time, rather than store info in a dict and then turn the dict into a data frame afterward?

Comment: Why can't you just do `members['x'] = calculate_x(members['id'])` and again for the 'y' column?

Comment: Not at all - I am unfamiliar with the dict object

Comment: You can just modify your `calculate_` code to accept a Series so it's vectorised

Comment: @EdChum, apologies for the misleading question. Pretend that x and y are random numbers created through each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: but you can generate a random array of values using any number of `np.random.randint` or whatever functions, it's really unnecessary generally to ever loop row-wise

Comment: Sorry - the point is not the random number functions. In my actual code, I am performing a number of calculations on different data sets. At the end of each for loop, I arrive at three values: x, y and an id. I need to aggregate this information some how, as I'm doing all of the above over a set of id's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of using a dict to build a dataframe:

```
dict_for_df = {}
for i in ('a','b','c','d'):    # Don't use "id" as a counter; it's a python function
    x = random.random()        # first value
    y = random.random()        # second value
    dict_for_df[i] = [x,y]     # store in a dict
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df) # after the loop convert the dict to a dataframe
```

Comment: This works - although I was getting my results transposed the wrong way. Instead of df=pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df) I used, df = DataFrame.from_dict(dict_for_df, orient='index')

Comment: Or just use "pd.DataFrame(dict_for_df).T" -- the "T" transposes the dataframe